# Java (and JBoss) JNDI and RMI ports

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jndi

I have JBoss running on a couple of Linux machines. If I want to send a JMS message from box 1 to a queue on box2, I may do something like this:

```
Hashtable<String,String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<String,String>();

jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://<ip of box2>:1099"); // 

InitialContext context = new InitialContext(m_jndiProperties);
Queue queue = (Queue)context.lookup("queue/myqueue");
```

and then put a message on the queue. Clearly port 1099 needs to be open on box2, but I am curious what other ports are involved in that communication?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Others I have off top of my head:

- Rmi: 1098.
- HornetQ acceptors / connectors: 5446 / 5445. Both configurable in `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/hornetq/hornetq-configuration.xml`

Comment: RMI only uses port 1098 for the Activation daemon, which isn't widely used.